# Преобразование int to short, Java

Tags: java

Необходимо вызвать метод `print(short value)` если `(val > 0 && val < 128)`.
Происходит вызов `print(Integer value)` игнорируя `(short)val`. В чём может быть проблема?

Ввод: `45`

Вывод: `Это тип Integer, значение 45`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String in = sc.next();
        while (!in.equals("exit")){
            try{
                int val = Integer.parseInt(in);
                print((val > 0 && val < 128)?(short)val:val);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Это не число");
            }
            in = sc.next();
        }
    }
    public static void print(short value) {
        System.out.println("Это тип short, значение " + value);
    }

    public static void print(Integer value) {
        System.out.println("Это тип Integer, значение " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема может быть в непонимании того, как работают тернарный оператор и выбор перегруженных функций.

---

Тернарный оператор возвращает более общий тип, если операнды имеют разные (но совместимые) типы.

Выбор перегруженной функции происходит на этапе компиляции.

---

```
if (val > 0 && val < 128)
  print((short)val);
else
  print(val);
```

Comment: Справедливо...
Спасибо, помогло